# I cannot run any of the sample applications that come with directx

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, directx

I downloaded the latest DirectX, I have Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2012.  When I open any of the sln files from the samples folder and try to build them, I get the same error "main entry point not found".

For example:

```
"Error  6   error X3501: 'main': entrypoint not found   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Samples\C++\Direct3D\ShadowMap\FXC ShadowMap"
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio 2012 by default is trying to compile the ".fx" shader code. You need to turn this off if you want to use a downloaded SDK (the most current version of the [DirectX SDK is now part of the Windows SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

The (old) DirectX SDK samples use the run-time HLSL compiler (via functions like `D3DX11CompileFromFile()`). ".fx" files are now by default compiled by Visual Studio 2012.

You need to select any ".fx" or ".hlsl" shader program files in VS2012 and set them to "exclude from build" (right-click the ".fx" file and select "Properties" > "General" > "Exclude from build" > "Yes").